# Problem about YouTubePlayer API for an application within a nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to setup Youtube video list using recyclerview within Fragment. 
I have an activity in that activity a fragment is there which manages bottom navigation selection another fragment is for tablayout which manages tab selection and final is the adapter in which I have my recyclerview which is setting up video list Everything is working as I planned but when I play video it YoutubePlayerAPI pause the video.
I tried fix this by searching on Google but not able fix.

below is my video_recycler_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/ivFeedCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#4f000000"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_video_play"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/video_container"
            android:tag="@string/video_component_tag">

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can any one tell what I am doing wrong in it?

I am getting message in logcat which I have mentioned below

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{f61352e VFED..... ........ 0,0-1080,1560 #7f0a01df app:id/rvFeed}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 24, top: 1402, right: 24, bottom: -422 (these should all be positive).
```

Comment: This error generally is being raised by their API. Long story short is that you don't have to overlay the video with absolutely anything. As per your xml, I am guessing that one / both `TextView`s from the bottom of layout may overlay the player.. check that out first.
I found [this](https://github.com/obipawan/youtube-recyclerview) example which may help you

Comment: I removed those `TextView`s but not solved my issue

Comment: Take a look at my edited comment. That git sample

Comment: I have seen that Example and I'm taking example from the same but not working

Comment: `The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 24, top: 1402, right: 24, bottom: -422 (these should all be positive).`

Is the video you're trying to play on-screen or what? looks like it's scrolled below the visible portion of the recyclerview.

Also, where's the `YoutubePlayerView` in your XML?

Comment: @Shark `YoutubePlayerView` is not present in XML that is created run time and yes I am trying to play video inside `RecyclerView`.

Comment: facing same issue `W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{5ff2951 VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1080,1560 #7f0a01da app:id/rvFeed}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: -1168, right: 0, bottom: 1918 (these should all be positive).` did you get the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid the pause, you need to hidden all views that overlay your framelayout, because I see that your frame is match_parent. When you do click in play video hide everything and try. Also look if you don´t have an FloatingActionButton or other view overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click play button at that time height of framLayout is 0 dp and also youtubePlayer.init("somevideID") will try to play the video but since height is 0 dp it just insert the video and pause the video.

This is what happening:

```
**Insert video 
Play the Video 
Height is Zero at insertion time 
So it pauses the video instantly**
```

So do one thing **add height** like 200dp to frameLayout and make it **invisible**. Now **before** calling youtubePlayer.init() make frameLayout **visible**. And **then** call youtubePlayer.init(). This will resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but same issue `W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.RelativeLayout{f0fb057 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1848}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 12, top: 646, right: 12, bottom: 602..`